# How to add a new dependency in requirements.txt file?

Tags: django, docker

I cloned a djangox repo to my local device

I founded a requirements.txt file that contains some dependencies
I wanna add a rest framework ( adding a new dependency ) to this file

how could I do that, please ?!
p.s: I usually use poetry that deals with pyproject.tomal
but for using docker, I wanna use this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual workflow for `requirements.txt` is:

1. Create a virtualenv for your project and activate it.
2. Run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all the dependencies into your virtualenv.
3. Run `pip install your_new_dependency` to add your new dependency to your virtualenv.
4. When you're happy with it, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to store a list of all packages in your current virtualenv in `requirements.txt`, updating it.

Comment: So I can't just add a new dependency without installing all the existing dependencies ?!

Comment: Well… you *could* just write the line into the file. It's just a text file. But then what? You probably want to use and test that dependency, and for that you probably need all the other dependencies too, no?