Package dependency management in Python compared to npm
Coming from JS/TS/npm and .NET/NuGet ecosystems I am struggling to understand Python's approach to package management. At this phase of learning, I am mostly interested in finding Python "close-to-equivalents" for common npm concepts and routine operations.
Is it fair to say that pyproject.toml and requirements.txt to Python are what package.json and package-lock.json to JavaScript, respectively?
Or the same question rephrased to attempt a reopen: Is pyproject.toml used to define general dependencies and versions, while requirements.txt specifies the exact resolved versions that can be used across different machines to achieve build consistency?

This is a slightly different question, but it contains the most recent answer I could find that could be relevant for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080546/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-develop-a-python-package-without-using-setup-py

The traditional workflow is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66567932/476. But since then, many new tools have been created which are more akin to npm and the like. See the duplicate above.

If you don't want to figure it out yourself from the dupe and linked documents, personally, I'd recommend https://python-poetry.org, which is pretty straightforward and npm-like.

The alternative to poetry is to throw the requirements into pyproject.toml and get rid of requirements.txt. There is old advice that you can do pip freeze > requirements.txt but you really shouldn't do that as it will pin everything including sub-dependencies and it'll be very brittle. If you want the top-level requirements, you can use pipreqs

Glad to hear about poetry again. Somehow I entirely forgot about it! ‍♂️ Having said that, I'm surprised that a lot of Python packages are only mentioning pip in their installation guides (e.g. Flask, SQLAlchemy, Marshmallow). In contrast, in JS, as a rule, you will see npm, yarn, and pnpm mentioned together... Speaking of friendlyness of the language to newbies, even though it's being commonly recommended as a good language to learn first.

@IgorSoloydenko pip really is the way forward to install things so I wouldn't dismiss it; it'll pull from PyPI. Where it becomes a train wreck is specifying all the dependencies for your own package because there are lots of different opinions on how to maintain it for package mgmt; that's been in flux for many years

That's probably cultural differences. PIP is the baseline standard. If you see pip install foo, you know to translate that into poetry add foo should you be using poetry. There's probably so many Python tools that it's unrealistic to mention them all.

This might help clarify pyproject.toml vs. requirements.txt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76548420. -- Note, though, that requirements.txt is not a real lock file like package.json. Some tools like PDM, uv, Poetry have their own lock file formats, but they are not compatible with each other. There is ongoing work to write a standard specification for a lockfile but it will take some more time until it is ready if ever (look up PEP 751 for the latest attempt).
